# Karaoke for Xbox

Tags: xbox-360

Is there any good Karaoke for XBox? I'm looking for popular songs that everybody know (like Shakira, Lady Gaga, anything really). I got GH5, but it was not made for singing (at least not for me).

Comment: As per our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), questions asking for shopping recommendations and game recommendations (including lists of games that qualify for a criteria) are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple that I can think of off the top of my head are...

[Lips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lips_%28video_game%29)

[Karaoke Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karaoke_Revolution)

Both have plenty of well known popular songs, though Im not sure if anything by Shakira or Lady Gaga

Comment: thx, i will check them out :)

Comment: Lips is the "main one", I think. There are music stores for it on Xbox Live featuring downloadable songs. Wikipedia has rather full lists of what is available in the retail boxes and as download.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_downloadable_songs_for_the_Lips_series

Comment: there seems to be some Lady Gaga songs, but not for Shakira.